# Getting RelativeLayout to work correctly at runtime

Tags: android, android-relativelayout

I'm trying to use a RelativeLayout to produce two rows of items, one row of three buttons up top with a scrollview below them.  I want the scrollView to occupy as much of the space as possible.

I believe a RelativeLayout is the best approach here.  I'm trying to do this at runtime and not via an xml layout file.  My code is as follows:

```
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams exitparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,  
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 


            exitparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);  

            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams zimparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,  
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams zoutparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,  
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams scrollparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,  
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

            zimparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT); 
            scrollparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_BOTTOM): 



            // Exit button
            Button exitbutton = new Button(this);
            exitbutton.setText("Exit");
            exitbutton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            exitbutton.setWidth(200);
            exitbutton.setLayoutParams(exitparams);


            // Zoom In button
            Button zoomOutButton = new Button(this);
            zoomOutButton.setText("Zoom Out");
            zoomOutButton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            zoomOutButton.setWidth(200);
            zoomOutButton.setLayoutParams(zimparams);


            // Zoom In button
            Button zoomInButton = new Button(this);
            zoomInButton.setText("Zoom In");
            zoomInButton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
            zoomInButton.setWidth(200);
            zoutparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, zoomInButton.getId());  

            zoomInButton.setLayoutParams(zoutparams);

            RelativeLayout layout1 = new RelativeLayout(this);  
            layout1.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));  
            layout1.addView(exitbutton);  
            layout1.addView(zoomInButton);  
            layout1.addView(zoomOutButton);  





            exitbutton.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   finish();
                }
            });

            zoomInButton.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    increaseZoom();
                    onResume();
                   }
            });

            zoomOutButton.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                   reduceZoom();
                   onResume();
                   }
            });

            drawView = new DrawView(this, height, width, SMD, zoomLevel);
            drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
            ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
            scrollView.addView(drawView);
            scrollView.setLayoutParams(scrollparams);

            layout1.addView(scrollView);
            setContentView(layout1);
```

Yet the only thing that shows up is the scrollView.  I'm guessing I'm missing something small here...  I read the documentation and I believe I did this correctly but the fact that it is not working suggests I either did something wrong or cannot accomplish what I want to do.

A visual of how I want this to look is as follows:

[image: layout]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `setContentView(layout1)` at the end to actually add the layout.

EDIT:

Okay so Iv'e fixed you code up and it's working on my phone. However I couldn't' work with `DrawView` obviously so if there is something wrong with that I can't help you. Give this a go.

```
     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams exitparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
             RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 


     exitparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);  

     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams zimparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
             RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams zoutparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,  
             RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT); 
     RelativeLayout.LayoutParams scrollparams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,  
             RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

     zimparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT); 




     // Exit button
     Button exitbutton = new Button(this);
     exitbutton.setText("Exit");
     exitbutton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
     exitbutton.setWidth(200);
     exitbutton.setLayoutParams(exitparams);
     exitbutton.setId(2);


     // Zoom In button
     Button zoomOutButton = new Button(this);
     zoomOutButton.setText("Zoom Out");
     zoomOutButton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
     zoomOutButton.setWidth(200);
     zoomOutButton.setLayoutParams(zimparams);
     zoomOutButton.setId(1);

     // Zoom In button
     Button zoomInButton = new Button(this);
     zoomInButton.setText("Zoom In");
     zoomInButton.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
     zoomInButton.setWidth(200);
     zoutparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, 1);  
     zoutparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, 2);  

     zoomInButton.setLayoutParams(zoutparams);

     RelativeLayout layout1 = new RelativeLayout(this);  
     layout1.setLayoutParams(new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));  
     layout1.addView(exitbutton);  
     layout1.addView(zoomInButton);  
     layout1.addView(zoomOutButton);  





     exitbutton.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();
         }
     });

     zoomInButton.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
             //increaseZoom();
             onResume();
            }
     });

     zoomOutButton.setOnClickListener (new View.OnClickListener() {
         public void onClick(View v) {
            //reduceZoom();
            onResume();
            }
     });

     //drawView = new DrawView(this, height, width, SMD, zoomLevel);
    // drawView.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
     ScrollView scrollView = new ScrollView(this);
     //scrollView.addView(drawView);
     scrollparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,1);
     scrollView.setLayoutParams(scrollparams);

     layout1.addView(scrollView);
     setContentView(layout1);
```

Comment: Well that explains the black void.  However after adding it I only see the scrollView....

Comment: Your relative layout params don't really make sense. Can you draw what you're trying to achieve? Make sure you use scrollparams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, layoutid); to position your scroll view under the buttons

Comment: where layoutid is the id of whatever you want it to be under. Maybe one of the buttons?

Comment: I'll get a picture here but what I want is the three buttons to be side by side in one row at the top and the scrollview to be below the three.

Comment: I've added a picture, hopefully I described this accurately earlier